# How do I customize a "require_from_group" error message and only display it once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that includes 15  elements, and is validated using jQuery validate plug in. These  elements all have the same class.

```
<select id="GGI" name="GGI" class="data">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="AB-GGI1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="AB-GGI2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<select id="GGJ" name="GGJ" class="data">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="GGJ1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="GGJ2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

I am validating them to make sure one is selected like this (using the additional-methods.min.js file) and showing the message in a modal (modal.open function):

```
$('#MyForm').validate({ 
    ignore:[],
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
    focusInvalid: false,
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var errors = "";
            if (validator.errorList.length > 0) {
                for (x=0;x<validator.errorList.length;x++) {
                    errors += '<li>' + validator.errorList[x].message + '</li>';
                }
            }
            $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#step3').offset().top}, 'slow');
            setTimeout(function(){
                modal.open({content:'<h2 class="l-twelve l-mb1 f-bold f-size18 f-l-height24 c-red">Please fix the errors below</h2><ul class="l-twelve l-redTriS">' + errors + '</ul>'});
            }, 750)

        }
        validator.focusInvalid();
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    var dataString = $(form).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:$('#MyForm').attr('method'),
        url: form.action,
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(data){
          $('input[type="submit"]').val('PROCESSING');
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(data.type == "error") {
                $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#step3').offset().top}, 'slow');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var errorMsg = '<ul><li>' + data.text + '</li></ul>';
                    modal.open({content:errorMsg, "width":"500px"});
                }, 750);
            }
            else if(data.type == 'success') {
                $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#MyForm').offset().top}, 'slow');
                $('#MyForm')[0].reset();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var successMsg = 'success msg here';
                    modal.open({content:successMsg, "width":"500px"});
                }, 750);

            }
        }
    });
    return false;
    },
    groups: {
        data: "GGI GGJ GGK GGL GGM GGN GG0 GGP GGQ GGR"
    },
    rules: {
        email2: {
            NoPeek: true
        },
        name:{
            required:true
        },
        email: {
            required:true,
            email:true
        },
        user_id:{
            required:true
        },
        auth: {
            required:true
        },
        acknowledge: {
            required:true
        },
        GGI:{
            require_from_group: [1, '.data']
        },
        GGJ:{
            require_from_group: [1, '.data']
        },
        GGK:{
            require_from_group: [1, '.data']
        },
        GGL:{
            require_from_group: [1, '.data']
        },
        GGM:{
            require_from_group: [1, '.data']
        },
        GGN:{
            require_from_group: [1, '.data']
        },
        GGO:{
            require_from_group: [1, '.data']
        },
        GGP:{
            require_from_group: [1, '.data']
        },
        GGQ: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.data']
        },
        GGR:{
            require_from_group: [1, '.data']
        }
    },
    messages:{
        name:{
            required:"Please enter your name"
        },
        email: {
            required:"Please enter your email address",
            email:"Please enter a valid email address"
        },
        user_id:{
            required:"Please enter your User ID"
        },
        auth: {
            required:"Please check the box"
        },
        acknowledge: {
            required: "You must acknowledge the  Agreement"
        },
        GGI:{
            require_from_group: "Please select an option prior to submitting."
        },
        GGJ:{
            require_from_group: "Please select an option prior to submitting."
        },
        GGK:{
            require_from_group: "Please select an option prior to submitting."
        },
        GGL:{
            require_from_group: "Please select an option prior to submitting."
        },
        GGM:{
            require_from_group: "Please select an option prior to submitting."
        },
        GGN:{
            require_from_group: "Please select an option prior to submitting."
        },
        GGO:{
            require_from_group: "Please select an option prior to submitting."
        },
        GGP:{
            require_from_group: "Please select an option prior to submitting."
        },
        GGQ: {
            require_from_group: "Please select an option prior to submitting."
        },
        GGR:{
            require_from_group: "Please select an option prior to submitting."
        }
    }
  });
});
```

After specifying each select in the "rules" and "messages" section. It still showed up with 15 errors instead of one for the group.

That works in the sense it makes you set a value for at least one of the group of  elements. I have 1 issues I cannot figure out - how to only show the error message once for the group. Right now you get the group error message 15 times. I am pretty sure it has something to do with this loop, how can I modify to only show the group error message once?

```
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var errors = "";
            if (validator.errorList.length > 0) {
                for (x=0;x<validator.errorList.length;x++) {
                    errors += '<li>' + validator.errorList[x].message + '</li>';
                }
            }
            $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#step3').offset().top}, 'slow');
            setTimeout(function(){
                modal.open({content:'Please fix the errors below<ul>' + errors + '</ul>'});
            }, 750)

        }
        validator.focusInvalid();
    },
```

Somewhere I need to tell the invalidHandler to only show one error if its parent has class .data

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, show what you actually did, because you started the question by describing part of the correct solution.  If that didn't work, let's see it so we can find the mistake and make it work with the modals.

Comment: I did show what I did, or at least I pasted in the code I was using. I know it's the loop, I need some way to limit the number of errors displayed for the group.

Comment: I meant that you should have also posted `.validate()` in its entirety.  Enough to reproduce.

Comment: Updated with entire validate() function

Comment: The `groups` option is only for grouping together error messages in the context of the default message placement.  When you use `.numberOfInvalids()` it's still looking at the actual number of invalid fields... same with the `.errorList`.  Maybe look at [the `showErrors` callback](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) instead and check out the `errorMap` object, which gives you the name of the field as well as the error message.

Comment: var summary = "You have the following errors: <br/>";
            $.each(errorList, function() { summary += " * " + this.message + "<br/>"; });
            $("#errorContainer").show().html(summary); This showed 15 of the same errors, it didn't seem to work with the group functon

Comment: You misunderstand if you think the `groups` option is going to work in this context.  When using the error lists and error maps, you're going to have to figure it out programatically.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. I will have to find another solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197627/discussion-between-dirty-bird-design-and-sparky).